# SQL Trigger is only updating row after a second row is added

Tags: sql

Behavior:
If i add 1 row the JB_RECIEVED_DATE is not being updated.

DOC_TRACK_MAIN table after 1st insert

```
MRG_JOB_ID| JB_REC_DATE
---------------------------------
00001     | null
```

JOBS table

```
JOB_ID | JOB_REC_DATE
--------------------------------
00001  | JUN-9-1999
00002  | JUN-17-2001
00003  | JUN-23-2008
```

If I add a second row the JB_RECIEVED_DATE is eing updated in row 1 but row 2 is not updated.

DOC_TRACK_MAIN table after 2nd insert

```
MRG_JOB_ID| JOB_REC_DATE
---------------------------------
00001     | JUN-9-1999
00002     | null
```

If I add row n only row n-1 is updated.

DOC_TRACK_MAIN table after nth insert

```
MRG_JOB_ID| JOB_REC_DATE
---------------------------------
00001     | JUN-9-1999
00002     | JUN-17-2001
00003     | null
```

My code for the trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "DB_1"."TRG_INSERT_REC_DATE" 
BEFORE INSERT ON DOC_TRACK_MAIN
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE DOC_TRACK_MAIN
    SET JB_RECEIVED_DATE = (SELECT JOB_RECEIVED_DATE FROM JOBS WHERE JOBS.JOB_ID=DOC_TRACK_MAIN.MRG_JOB_ID);
END;
```

Comment: Maybe it's because your trigger is firing BEFORE the insert?

Comment: The syntax appears to be Oracle but the question isn't tagged Oracle and no database is mentioned.  Are you actually using Oracle?

Comment: The issue was solved by creating a view that incorporates both tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is what happens. Assume you have no record in your DOC_TRACK_MAIN table. As your Trigger is Before Insert, this means the Update statement won't find any row to update. After your first insert happens, you now have one record. When you insert another record to that table, Before inserting the trigger will go and update the only row that has a matching value in the JOBS table. When you insert the third record, the trigger will update the two previously inserted records and so on. So in fact, all your records are getting updated before you insert the next record, not the last one. It's really updating all the records, but you only notice the last one because, the last one was null before inserting the new one and the others had values from the JOBS table. It has the same effect of setting a column to its current value like this:

```
UPDATE TABLE1 SET COL1=COL1, COL2=COL2;
```

Will you notice the update if you do the above?

Comment: The issue was solved by creating a view that incorporates both tables, but your suggestion was answer that led us back to that conclusion. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what DBMS this is, but if it's anything like a SQL Server trigger, you would need some identifier of the inserted data - as it is right now it looks like you're updating ***all*** data in the table every time the trigger fires.

In addition as the other answer/comments have stated, you're firing your trigger prior to inserting the record, so the newly inserted record is not impacted by the trigger.

The trigger all in all seems unnecessary in this instance - why not just change your insert statement to insert the date as well?

e.g.

```
insert into DOC_TRACK_MAIN (MRG_JOB_ID, JB_REC_DATE)
select '00003' , JOB_RECEIVED_DATE 
FROM JOBS 
WHERE JOBS.JOB_ID=DOC_TRACK_MAIN.MRG_JOB_ID
```

If that for some reason does not work for you, you'll need to look into your RDBMS' documentation for the "inserted" keyword that is referenced in triggers to affect only the data being manipulated, rather than the entire table's data.  Imagine if your table had 50 million rows in it, each time you made any inserts into the table an update on all 50 million rows would occur - even though they are (likely) being updated to the same value